# Computing some fundamental groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm studying algebraic topology and got stuck.

a. $X_n\in \mathbb{R}^3$ is the union of $n$ distinct lines through the origin. Find $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3-X_n)$ for each $n$.

b. Let $X$ be the sum of two tori $S_1\times S_1$ by identifying a circle $S_1\times x_0$ in a torus with $S_1\times x_0$ of the other torus. Find $\pi_1(X)$.

For (a), $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3-X_1)=\mathbb{Z}.$ But I cannot compute $n\ge 2$ cases.. for (b), I guess the group is $<a,b,c|ab=ba,bc=cb>$ from Van Kampen. Is it correct?

Comment: $a$ is the same as a sphere with $2n$ holes.

Comment: For (b), you should notice that a cross section of $X$ looks like a figure 8 (you should imagine $X$ as being two doughnuts lying one on top of the other), so $X$ is homeomorphic to $(S^1 \vee S^1)\times S^1$. Of course, it's always a good idea to get practice using Van Kampen's theorem so definitely use that method too to do the calculation.

Comment: Thanks, Michael and Daniel :)

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?). Your question (a) is a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/129380/10014), and your question (b) is a duplicate of [that question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/929969/10014). I'm voting to close as duplicate of the first one.