# How do you find the Cartesian product of $S^1 \times 8$ in topology?

Tags: general-topology

So, when we find the Cartesian product of two spaces, the Cartesian product will be connected, right?  Also, what will be the cartesian product if we just flipped it to $8 \times S^1$.(Here 8 is a number, same as joining two circles).

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/930001/11619) is a picture of $8\times S^1$.  To comment your first question: the Cartesian product of two **connected** spaces will be connected. If one factor has several connectivity components so does the product. And, the mapping $(x,y)\mapsto (y,x)$ is always a homemorphism between  $X\times Y$ and $Y\times X$.

Comment: This was really helpful. Does the opposite of that $S^1 \times 8$ the same?